# vb.net 2015 datagridview export to xml file

Tags: vb.net

I am new to visual studio and I need any kind of help.

My project is to read an .xlsx file to a datagridview and export all the data to a .ini file and a .xml file, In order for a controller to handle it. I have done some work until now but I am stacked on how to export the datagridview to an xml file. Any help is acceptable.

Thanks a lot.

Here is a pic of my project in design mode: [datagridview to Xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WuDM.jpg)

And my code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports IniFile
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim Ds As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyAdapter As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Pratto_lp3\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\SCHEDULE.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'")
            MyAdapter = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [S-BOTTOM_(1)$]", MyConnection)
            Ds = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyAdapter.Fill(Ds)
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)

    Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)
        MsgBox("ExcelFile File Loaded")
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        TextBox1.Text = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim writer As System.IO.StreamWriter
    Dim sa As Integer
    writer = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("c:\users\pratto_lp3\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\DtgrdToText.ini", True)
    For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1
        Integer.TryParse(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString, sa)

        If sa > 0 And sa < 50 Then
            writer.WriteLine(String.Format("[row{0}]", i))             '              
            writer.WriteLine("Design No ", sa.ToString)

            For j As Integer = 1 To 15 Step +1
                writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}={1}", j.ToString, DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString))
                '               
            Next
            writer.WriteLine(String.Empty)
        End If
    Next
    writer.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
End Sub
End Class
```

Below is what I have tried so far on how to save the xml to folder:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    'define a save dialog
    Dim filePath As String = "c: \users\pratto_lp3\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\DtgrdToText.xml"
    Dim save_file As New SaveFileDialog
    save_file.Filter = "xml files (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        save_file.FilterIndex = 2
        Dim my_datatable As New DataTable
        If save_file.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            my_datatable = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
            my_datatable.WriteXml(save_file.FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Look at [XElement Class Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387085(v=vs.110).aspx) to begin with.

Comment: Please update your question rather than submitting question updates as answer. See my question edit.

Comment: Is it ok now Daniel?I have edited my post..

Comment: Ahhh.. If only you'd loaded your XLSX file into a datatable (probably 3 lines of code), you could have showed the whole thing in a datagridview in one line of code, and written an XML file from it with another line of code..